# Sorting a vector of struct causes Visual Studio to throw a popup with "Debug Assertion Failed"

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, opencv

I have a simple Rectangle struct with x, y, width, and height, which I thought would be easy to work with vectors but it turned out to be pretty messy.

This is what I have in main:

```
vector<CvRect> v;
v.push_back(cvRect(50,0,50, 50));
v.push_back(cvRect(150, 0, 50,50));
v.push_back(cvRect(100, 0, 50,50));
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), rectangleCmpByPosition);
```

I have this declared in my header

```
static int rectangleCmpByPosition(const CvRect &a, const CvRect &b);
```

with this as definition:

```
static int rectangleCmpByPosition(const CvRect& a, const CvRect &b){
    if (a.y != b.y){
        return a.y - b.y;
    }else{
        return a.x - b.x;
    }
}
```

And visual studio throws this error message at me[image].

I spent the whole afternoon googling to see what I did wrong but I can't find the cause. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparator is incorrect.  The comparator needs to return a `bool`:  `true` if `a` is "less than" `b` and `false` otherwise.  It needs to provide a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew it was something silly like that.